# Laravel 10 - reuse vue 2 components

Tags: vuejs2, laravel-10

We currently have an application that was originally built using Laravel 5 on the backend and Vue.js 2 on the frontend. Now, we're embarking on a project to rewrite this application, aiming to use Laravel 10 as the backend framework. The key goal is to recycle the Vue.js 2 components from our previous project. In our earlier project, we utilized Laravel Mix for asset management. However, based on our understanding, Laravel 10 incorporates a new tool called Vite for frontend development.

The primary question at hand is whether it's feasible to employ Vue.js 2 alongside our existing Vue.js 2 components from the previous project, leveraging Laravel 10 in combination with Laravel Mix. This decision hinges on compatibility and the viability of integrating Vue.js 2 components into the Laravel 10 and Laravel Mix ecosystem